# Parse XML to more efficient maps code?

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, marker, polyline

Ok. I'm not a java or android programmer but I write a code for a maps app where a bus route showing the bus stops are overlap using especific color and markers. The code works, but the route will require a lot more points to follow the bus road, mainly the same code with different LatLng values for markers and polylines. I think in parsing some xml into an array and a loop but: 1) After follow a lot of tutorials I didn't know how do it the way I wanted and 2) I preffer not to use an external XML as I wanted my app not to be too much Internet deppendant (only for cache the maps, or update the routes XML's)

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<iLPbus>
<iLPbus_Route conuter="1">
    <iLPbus_Route_name>Inca Llojeta->PUC</iLPbus_Route_name>
    <iLPbus_Route_icon>R.drawable.ic_illojeta</iLPbus_Route_icon>
    <iLPbus_Route_Polyline>
        <poly_color>0xff81488e</poly_color>
        <point counter="1">
            <lat>-16.529183</lat>
            <lng>-68.143298</lng>
        </point>    
        <point counter="2">
            <lat>-16.534203</lat>
            <lng>-68.14593</lng>
        </point>
        <point counter="3">
            <lat>-16.532493</lat>
            <lng>-68.142459</lng>
        </point>
        <point counter="4">
            <lat>-16.533225</lat>
            <lng>-68.140485</lng>
        </point>
        <point counter="5">
            <lat>-16.533513</lat>
            <lng>-68.137939</lng>
        </point>
        <point counter="6">
            <lat>-16.534187</lat>
            <lng>-68.134404</lng>
        </point>
        <point counter="7">
            <lat>-16.533058</lat>
            <lng>-68.131521</lng>
        </point>
    </iLPbus_Route_Polyline>
    <iLPbus_BusStops counter="1">
        <lat>-16.529183</lat>
        <lng>-68.143298</lng>
        <name>R. Tupac Katari</name>
    </iLPbus_BusStops>
    <iLPbus_BusStops counter="2">
        <cords>
            <lat>13.72331</lat>
            <lng>100.78453999999999</lng>
        </cords>
        <name>Raul Salmón</name>
    </iLPbus_BusStops>
</iLPbus_Ruta>
</iLPbus>
```

**The Java: (before implement parser)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class MapaMoradoaPUCActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa_morado_apuc);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    setUpMapIfNeeded(extras);
}

protected void onResume(Object extras) {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded(extras);
}

private void setUpMap(Object extras) {
    // RUTA MORADA Inca Llojeta hacia PUC
    LatLng RM01aPUC = new LatLng(-16.529183, -68.143298);
    LatLng RM02aPUC = new LatLng(-16.534203, -68.14593);
    LatLng RM03aPUC = new LatLng(-16.532493, -68.142459);
    LatLng RM04aPUC = new LatLng(-16.533225, -68.140485);
    LatLng RM05aPUC = new LatLng(-16.533513, -68.137939);
    LatLng RM06aPUC = new LatLng(-16.534187, -68.134404);
    LatLng RM07aPUC = new LatLng(-16.533058, -68.131521);
    LatLng RM08aPUC = new LatLng(-16.529911, -68.128731);
    LatLng RM09aPUC = new LatLng(-16.531228, -68.126199);
    LatLng RM10aPUC = new LatLng(-16.526527, -68.126339);
    LatLng RM11aPUC = new LatLng(-16.525992, -68.123598);
    LatLng RM12aPUC = new LatLng(-16.523153, -68.1218);
    LatLng RM13aPUC = new LatLng(-16.520057, -68.125395);
    LatLng RM14aPUC = new LatLng(-16.517146, -68.121607);
    LatLng RM15aPUC = new LatLng(-16.514277, -68.11444);
    LatLng RM16aPUC = new LatLng(-16.503846, -68.12856);
    LatLng RM17aPUC = new LatLng(-16.500287, -68.132014);
    LatLng RM18aPUC = new LatLng(-16.500719, -68.130083);

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    if (extras != null) {
        int number = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("keyMap");
        if (number == 1) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM01aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 2) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM02aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 3) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM03aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 4) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM04aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 5) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM05aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 6) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM06aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 7) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM07aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 8) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM08aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 9) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM09aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 10) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM10aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 11) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM11aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 12) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM12aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 13) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM13aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 14) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM14aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 15) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM15aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 16) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM16aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 17) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM17aPUC, 16));
        }
        if (number == 18) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(RM18aPUC, 16));
        }
    }

    // Trazar Rutas

    // RUTA MORADA Inca Llojeta hacia PUC
    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true).color(0xff81488e).width(5)
            .add(RM01aPUC).add(RM02aPUC).add(RM03aPUC).add(RM04aPUC)
            .add(RM05aPUC).add(RM06aPUC).add(RM07aPUC).add(RM08aPUC)
            .add(RM09aPUC).add(RM10aPUC).add(RM11aPUC).add(RM12aPUC)
            .add(RM13aPUC).add(RM14aPUC).add(RM15aPUC).add(RM16aPUC)
            .add(RM17aPUC).add(RM18aPUC));

    // Añadir marcadores
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM01aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("R. Tupac Katari"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM02aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Raul Salmón"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM03aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("UE José Santos Vargas"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM04aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Final Buenos Aires"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM05aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Centro de Salud El Vergel"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM06aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Vergelito"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM07aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Tomillo"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM08aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Las Petunias"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM09aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Las Acacias"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM10aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("H. Nuestra Sra. de La Paz"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM11aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("UE Boliviano Japones"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM12aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("R. Cementerio Jardín"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM13aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Emaverde"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM14aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Puentes Trillizos"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM15aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("4to Centenario"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM16aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC").title("UMSA"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM17aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Plaza Camacho"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_illojeta))
            .position(RM18aPUC).snippet("Inka Llojeta->PUC")
            .title("Simón Bolivar"));
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(Object extras) {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
    // map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.paradasmoradas)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap(extras);
        }
    }
}
}
```

What should you recommend??

Answer (score 0):

Since you have fixed routes represented though polylines and bus stops represented through markers, I would recommend to store them in a table in the SQLite Database that is inbuilt in Android SDK. Whenever the user install your application this data will always persists whether he is online or offline. The runtime features such as Location Listener, finding route from one place to another can be achieved when the user is online but they can be cached again. As parsing XML is an expensive operation and the user has to be connected to internet each time, storing the route data for fixed paths is a good option for now.

Please follow the [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/storing-and-retrieving-locations-in-sqlite-from-google-maps-android-api-v2/) and [this](http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/storing-gps-points-in-sqlite-db.html) [link](http://android.bigresource.com/Android-Displaying-Longitude-Latitude-values-stored-in-a-SQLite-bATK0BYuI.html) to know more about storing lat lang in SQLite DB.

Hope this would Help!!!